# protobuf successfully installed but cannot import

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

I installed tensorflow 1.13.1 and protobuf 3.6.1. successfully. But when I tried to import protobuf 3.6.1, an error occurs. I used python 3.6.0

Error is given below:

import protobuf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'protobuf'

because of this i cannot import tensorflow

Comment: How did you install `tensorflow`? What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 @LukaszTracewski

Comment: How did you install it? That was my first question.

Comment: pip install tensorflow==1.13.1 pip install protobuf 3.6.1 python 3.6.0

Comment: Do other installed modules import correctly? If you install e.g. `scipy`, will it import? In the command line, run `where python`. Also, you can try running e.g. `python -c 'import h5py; print(h5py.__version__)' ` to see if you can import other Python dependency.

Comment: Yes, both scipy 1.2.1 and h5py 2.9.0 imported successfully

Comment: Python 3.6 is pretty old, I'd probably switch to the latest. That being said, going down the rabbit hole would mean probably 10 more questions. Would you consider using Anaconda? Anaconda better encapsulates the environment and all non-Python dependencies. Also, it's worth noting that `tensorflow` is (much) faster on Anaconda.

Comment: The Anaconda version only supports python 3.7. and tensorflow supports only python 3.6.0.(tensorflow does not support python 3.7). so switching will not work.

Comment: Uhm, no and no :). `conda create -n yourenvname tensorflow` installs tensorflow with latest supported Python. You can be explicit too: `conda create -n yourenvname tensorflow python=3.6`. Note omitting "0". This gets you the latest Pythn 3.6, in this case 3.6.8. Tensorflow works with the latest. Do you want to give it a try?

Comment: I installed it using pip.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski I tried to install tensorflow using conda and successfully installed and imported. but still protouf is not importing.

Comment: Sure, because they have peculiar way of importing it. See my answer. Hopefully this resolves the problem and you can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in comments, working with `pip` to get tensorflow running on this particular system turned out to be *complicated*. Instead, we went with [Anaconda installation](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python):

```
conda create -n yourenvname tensorflow
```

To import `protobuf`:

```
import google.protobuf
```

Comment: I tried this way but still protobuf is not imported.